# About the square of orthogonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

If $Q^2$ is an orthogonal matrix, is $Q$ an orthogonal matrix? If not, what is the reason or could you please give me a counterexample?

Comment: What have you tried? What do you think?

Comment: I think in the complex case, maybe? We may need $Q^2 \in \operatorname{SO}(n)$, perhaps, to avoid $\det Q = \pm i$.

Comment: I think this is not true,but i cannot think of any reasonable explanations.because if Q is an orthogonal matrix can lead to the fact thatQ^2 is an orthogonal matrix,so i naturally think about the reverse direction

Comment: Well,the discussion is restricted in R^(n*n)

Comment: $$ Q=  \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & \frac{1}{5} \\ 5 & 0 \end{array}  \right)  $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the matrix

$$Q=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\-2&-1\end{pmatrix}$$

Clearly, $Q$ is not orthogonal, but

$$Q^2=\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$

is orthogonal.

Comment: @WillJagy Yes, I saw this comment in the above section. Why did you comment this here?